# Creating RTF in AppleScript from emails: How to deal with the encoding of mails?

Tags: character-encoding, applescript

I have the following AppleScript within a workflow that runs on a OS X 10.10.5:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "Mail"
    set _sel to get selection
    set _links to {}
    repeat with _msg in _sel
        set _messageURL to _msg's message id
        set _messageTitle to _msg's subject
    end repeat

    set cmd to "\"{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf949\\cocoasubrtf270{\\fonttbl
        \\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 Helvetica;}{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}
        \\margl1440\\margr1440\\vieww9000\\viewh8400\\viewkind0\\pard\\tx720\\tx1440
        \\tx2160\\tx2880\\tx3600\\tx4320\\tx5040\\tx5760\\tx6480\\tx7200\\tx7920\\tx8640
        \\ql\\qnatural\\pardirnatural{\\field{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \"message:///%3c" & 
        _messageURL & "%3e\"}}{\\fldrslt\\f0\\fs28 \\cf0 \"" & _messageTitle & "\"}}}\""

    do shell script "/bin/bash -c 'echo " & cmd & " | pbcopy -Prefer rtf'"
  end tell
  return input
end run
```

The script is able to create a RFT link to a mail message that I can copy from the clipboard elsewhere. However, when the subject of the email contains non ASCII characters the script is incapable to deal with them. For example, given the following subject in Spanish (it can be translated as *I'll be in Zaragoza on Monday, 7th, sept 2015*)

```
Re: Estaré en zaragoza el lunes 7 sept 2015
```

The text that is be pasted is:

```
Re: EstarâˆšÂ© en zaragoza el lunes 7 sept 2015
```

I guess that I must encode the value of `_messageTitle` to from `utf-8` to `ansicpg1252` but I am unsure of this guessing and I haven't find a post dealing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to convert the output, as you guessed. Here’s a simpler example that duplicates your problem:

```
on run
    set _messageTitle to "Résolu"

    set fullCommand to "/bin/bash -c 'echo " & _messageTitle & "'" & " | pbcopy"

    do shell script fullCommand
end run
```

On pasting, the accented é is messed up.

One solution is to run the output of `echo` through `iconv`:

```
on run
    set _messageTitle to "Résolu"

    set fullCommand to "/bin/bash -c 'echo " & _messageTitle & "'" & " | iconv -t MACROMAN -f UTF8-MAC | pbcopy"

    do shell script fullCommand
end run
```

On pasting, the accented é is correctly accented.

Note that you may have to use different to (`-t`) and from (`-f`) encodings, depending on your situation.

Comment: The better solution that I've found is to use `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` so `ó` is converted into `'o`. I think that the problem could be also in the RTF code and/or how the string is processed by `do shell script`.